# Angular 2, Firebase -> SignInWithRedirect()

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

**Firebase** Using **SignInWithRedirect()** function, **it signs in but .user variable is returned null** and also cannot login to home page. Instead it redirects and **loops back to the same login page** always. How can I make this right?

The Google Sign In Typescript code is given below.

```
googleLogin(){

var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();  
var profile = firebase.auth().currentUser; 

provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly');
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'); 

  if (!profile) {   
    this.afauth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider);

    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then((gsignres) => {

        if(gsignres.user != null){
          alert('redirect success!');
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
        } else{
          alert('Sign in Failed!');
        }


      }).catch((err) => {
        alert(err);
      });  

  } else {
    alert('else part of if');
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
    alert('root set!!!!');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an infinite loop. You call `signInWithRedirect` and then call `getRedirectResult` successively. You will always try to sign in every time you come back to the page.

What you need to do is first determine the user state via:
`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
   if (user) {
     // Already signed in.
   } else {
     // not signed in.
   }
 })`

If there is no user, show a button to sign in which on click, call `signInWithRedirect`.
If there is a user, you can call `getRedirectResult()` if you want to get the credential returned from the sign-in. Though this will only be available if the user just signed in, otherwise it is null.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. But i removed the getredirectresult() and tested the code. I believe it is an issue with the signinwithredirect(). I tried to set the rootpage to the home page after signinwithredirect(). Just after the sign in it pushes the home page view but after a while again comes back to the login page. I added the above give code snippet also to check if the user is already signed in. But thats not the problem. Can you help me with this? thanks a lot!